# How to compress data in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, base64, compression, nsdata

I have some files in file manager in Swift 3. I want to upload them, but when I will convert them into base 64, their size will be huge! so I want to compress the data before converting it into base 64.

Here is my code for converting:

```
for i in 0...(rows?.count)! - 1 {

   let filePath = filesurl[fileManagerViewController.selectedFileIndex[i]]
        do {
            let fileData = try Data.init(contentsOf: filePath)

            let fileStream:String = fileData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))

            fileManagerViewController.upupload.append(fileStream)


        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }


        }
```

I used

```
let compressedData = fileData(UF_COMPRESSED)
```

But that didn't work for me, so please help me compressing files before converting them into base 64 for uploading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's `libcompression` wrapper written in Swift 3. 
https://github.com/mw99/SwiftDataCompression

> Swift libcompression wrapper as an extension for the Data type (ZLIB, LZFSE, LZMA, LZ4, deflate, RFC-1950, RFC-1951)

So you can compress your data like that:

```
let fileData = try Data.init(contentsOf: filePath)
let compressedData = fileData.compress(withAlgorithm: .LZFSE)
```

Answer (score 5):

For reference, as of Swift 5.1 the way to do this is:

```
let compressedData = fileData.compress(withAlgorithm: .LZFSE) as Data
```